# Crop Image to circle shape with 1:1 aspect ratio

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Am trying to get a script which will crop image in a circle shape with aspect ratio 1:1, below are the script I am trying but it's cropping in oval shape.

```
Sub CropToCircle()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)

    If shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or shp.Type = msoPicture Then
        shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you researched Shape.ScaleHeight or Shape.ScaleWidth? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.scaleheight

Comment: Yes I have gone through that, but no success

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions of the whatever crop shape you choose are dependent on the original shape. If you have a square shape and apply `msoShapeOval`, your crop area will be a circle. But if your original image shape is rectangular you have two options:

1. If the `.LockAspectRatio` of the shape is `msoFalse`, then you can modify the width or height to create a square image, then apply your crop and it will come out as a circle.
2. If the `.LockAspectRatio` of the shape is `msoTrue` and you can't change it (i.e. it would distort the original image in an undesireable way), then you need a different approach.

Starting out with a single slide in a presentation and a single (image) shape on the slide

[image]

The idea is to add a rectangle overlaid in the same size (width and height) as the original image, then create a circle on top of the rectangle in the size (diameter) you need. In the example below, I'm using a (random) circle size of 80% of the height of the original image. Then, combine the two shapes (rectangle and circle) into a single shape -- a rectangle with a hole in the middle. Finally, set the background and border colors of the mask shape to be the same as the slide background.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CropToCircle()
    Dim ppt As Presentation
    Set ppt = ActivePresentation

    Dim theSlide As Slide
    Set theSlide = ppt.Slides(1)

    Dim ogPicture As Shape
    Set ogPicture = theSlide.Shapes(1)

    With ogPicture
        If (.Type = msoLinkedPicture) Or (.Type = msoPicture) Then
            Dim maskRectangle As Shape
            Dim maskCircle As Shape
            Set maskRectangle = theSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
                                                         Left:=.Left, _
                                                         Top:=.Top, _
                                                         Width:=.Width, _
                                                         Height:=.Height)

            '--- randomly decided the circle mask should be 80% of the
            '    height of the original image
            Const MASK_SIZE As Double = 0.8
            Dim circleDiameter As Double
            circleDiameter = .Height * MASK_SIZE

            Set maskCircle = theSlide.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, _
                                                      Left:=(.Left + ((.Width / 2) - (circleDiameter / 2))), _
                                                      Top:=(.Top + (.Height * ((1# - MASK_SIZE) / 2#))), _
                                                      Width:=circleDiameter, _
                                                      Height:=circleDiameter)

            Dim maskShapes As Variant
            maskShapes = Array(maskRectangle.Name, maskCircle.Name)
            theSlide.Shapes.Range(maskShapes).MergeShapes msoMergeCombine

            '--- find the shape we just created
            Dim maskShape As Shape
            For Each maskShape In theSlide.Shapes
                If maskShape.Name <> .Name Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next maskShape

            '--- the color of the new make shape and it's border has to match
            '    the color of the slide background, assuming it's solid
            maskShape.Fill.ForeColor = theSlide.Background.Fill.BackColor
            maskShape.Line.ForeColor = theSlide.Background.Fill.BackColor

            '--- optionally group the mask and the original image
            theSlide.Shapes.Range(Array(.Name, maskShape.Name)).Group

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, this is not a true crop and only an approximation and will only work if your slide background is a solid color (not a pattern or gradient).

Comment: The Output is exactly the same what I needed, but the issue is when I apply Shadow it applies on the rectangle shape, which I don't needed.

Comment: Curiously, I can do exactly what you want manually but cannot replicate it in VBA. If I only create a circle on top of the image, then select the image first and the circle second (multiselect), then choose Merge Shapes using Intersect, you get exactly what you want. I haven't been able to get VBA to accomplish the same thing yet.

Comment: I Understand, we can do Manually but we have a multiple images where I wanted to apply these things, that's the reason I needed in vba where I can apply on multiple pictures at a same time.

Answer (score 0):

This approach would be much more simple compared to other alternatives.

```
// Crop 1:1
shape.Select();
CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PictureCropAspectRatio1To1");

// To convert to oval
if (shape.AutoShapeType != MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval &&
    shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
{
    shape.AutoShapeType = MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval;
}
```